# PHP: Find last charactor position in strpos

Tags: php, string, strpos

suppose there is string like `localhost/images/pic-1.jpg`.
I'm trying to find the position of `s` but not the`/` in `/images` word using `strpos()`, I can achieve this by `strpos('localhost/images/pic-1.jpg','/images')+7` but it is not pleasant.

Comment: Sorry, your question is vague and unclear. Please take the time to write a proper and understandable question if you expect a helpful answer. Thanks.

Comment: do you mean `strrpos` ?

Comment: @Andrew no . `strrpos` wont lead to right answer . im not looking for last occurrence of a certain character but looking for index of the end of a substring within a large string begining from start of the large string as @Mureinik described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're trying to find the index of the **end** of a substring within a larger string as opposed to its beginning, which `strpos` would return.

Your approach seems to be right, although it could be generalized a tad:

```
function strendpos ($haystack, $needle) {
    $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);
    if ($pos) {
        $pos += strlen($needle);
    }
    return $pos;
}
```

Comment: thanks, please correct `needle` to `$needle` in second line :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code:

```
strpos('/images', 's');
```

it will return the position of 's'.

Comment: exellent. but what if i am looking for second `/` position  in `/images/`?

Comment: strpos('localhost/images/pic-1.jpg', 'es/'); 

++ 2 char for 'es'

Comment: @AbedAlzain what exactly are  you trying to accomplish, I think there is a better way.

Comment: @kurt Sorry, I answered his question, he want to use strpos to find 's' in '/images' word, I sent an example for it.

Comment: @AbedAlzain sorry! Somehow I mistook you for the poster.